# ifstream linker error

Tags: c++, file, file-io, include, undefined-reference

I am trying to read in a file. I attempt to use ifstream in read() but I get the following error.

> undefined reference to `std::basic_ifstream<char,
>   std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ifstream()'
>   /home/ameya/Documents/computer_science/cs130B/prog2/prog2.cpp:24:
>   undefined reference to`std::basic_ifstream >::~basic_ifstream()' prog2.o:(.eh_frame+0x6b):
>   undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make: *** [prog2] Error 1

It says undefined reference to ifstream but I included that at the top so, why am I getting that error? Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ifstream>

using namespace std;

class DepthMap{
public:
  int merge(int numbers[]);
  int mergehelper(int left[], int right[]);
  void read();
};

int DepthMap::merge(int numbers[]){
  return -43;
}

int DepthMap::mergehelper(int left[], int right[]){
  return -43;
}

void DepthMap::read(){
  ifstream inputFile;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  DepthMap depth;

  printf("Here");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my Makefile

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

all: prog2

prog2: prog2.o

clean:
    rm -f prog2
```

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <fstream>` as it should be.

Your `g++` seems to be broken. Why do you not install `clang`?

Here are some suggested corrections for your makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

prog2: prog2.o
      g++ $(CXXFLAGS) prog2.o -o prog2
prog2.o: prog2.cpp
      g++ $(CXXFLAGS) prog2.cpp -o prog2.o
clean:
    rm -f prog2
```

Comment: Im using ubuntu so do I still need cygwin?

Comment: @Ameya Savale: My answer explains why your Makefile was doing the wrong thing.

Comment: -1: There's no need to add an explicit target for the object file. That part was working fine via the implicit rule. Also, the rule for linking should use $(LDFLAGS) rather than $(CXXFLAGS). This answer isn't helping the OP understand why its failing.

Comment: @Troubadour adding explicit target rules does not hurt. Secondly `-Wall` is _NOT_ a linker flag.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is

```
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: that would throw an error during preprocessing, if he were looking for that.

Comment: undefined reference to `std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream()'
/home/ameya/Documents/computer_science/cs130B/prog2/prog2.cpp:24: undefined reference to `std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_fstream()'
prog2.o:(.eh_frame+0x6b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @AmeyaSavale, that means you're using gcc instead of g++ to compile. What program are you using?

Comment: When you're compiling, use "g++ prog2.cpp -o test" and then "./test" to run it

Answer (score 1):

You are using `gcc` to compile and link rather than `g++`. By using the latter it will make sure you link against libstdc++.so without having to explicitly add it.

Seeing your Makefile confirms the above for linking.

Although you define `CXX` to be g++ that is only used for the implicit rule that compiles the source file. The implicit rule for linking falls back to `CC` which will probably be `gcc`. See the [Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for GNU make.

Comment: im using g++ here is my Makefile

Comment: CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
       
all: prog2
         
prog2: prog2.o
             
clean:
 rm -f prog2

Comment: your makefile makes no sense @AmeyaSavale

Comment: sorry the formatting messed it up I added it as an edit to the original post

Comment: @Aniket: My answer doesn't say anything about implicit versus explicit. Nor does my comment on your answer (it only points out that the OP's original implicit rule for the object file was not the source of their error). Looks like you are dowvoting out of spite. My answer answers the question exactly whereas yours just shrugs its shoulders and offers an alternative.

Comment: a comment such as "better" doesn't merit a down vote. Down votes, IMO, are to be used when the answer is wrong or doesn't address the problem. I think @Troubadour got to the heart of the issue. I found it useful whereas the "accepted" solution to use "clang" totally skirts the issue.